# Why chrome use a temporary file and then rename it when downloading files?

Tags: google-chrome, filesystems, file-management, temporary-files

I'm now impelmenting a simple download utility. I don't know why chrome need a temporary file when downloading from the Internet and then rename it, instead of downloading the file directly with its name. For file consistency? Or other reasons?

Thanks and best regards.

Comment: Ask the Chrome developers.  Unless one of us is one of them, this question cannot be definitively answered.

Comment: Personally, if I were a Chrome developer, I might do it this way so users don't edit still-downloading files. But yeah, we aren't the ones in charge, so it's anyone's guess.

Comment: @mdpc You're right, but there is not website superdeveloper.com :). Anyway, thanks for your comment.

Comment: Doesn't Chrome have a SDK for developing addons? Why not check what's defined in there? That way, you don't have to guess yourself, or ask people who don't develop apps.

Answer (score 6):

Many downloading programs create temporary files that they rename to the final name after the download is complete. That way nobody can mistake a partially downloaded file with the final results.